# Unreal Remote API - function call not triggering animations

Tags: unreal-engine5

I'm trying to trigger a number of different of animations to play using the Unreal Engine Remote HTTP API. The animations are plugged into a Blend Pose node to get smooth, weighted transitions between the animation states. I have a custom function on the Actor BP that takes a string and converts it to the corresponding ENUM value and sets the public variable on the Animation Blueprint to trigger the Blend. This all works perfectly when triggered via a UI Widget.

Now to the remote call. I have used the output log command line to permanently enable the WebServer. Then, using Postman to simulate an API call, I first start my PIE session, then I query my actors to get the proper spawned actor blueprint path.

Then I perform a remote call on the function on the actor blueprint, using the spawned instance of the actor blueprint to make sure I'm targeting the PIE version.

The function actually executes (I see the printString statements on my Unreal viewport).

However, despite printing all the debug messages at all the right times, the triggered animation does not play.

I should point out that I know the function works because I also have it wired up to a Widget with buttons that use the exact same function in the exact same way, getting the exact same debug text output, but triggering the animations.

When I call that very same function from the remote API call, and see the very same debug output, the animations do not trigger.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are sure, it is working the other way (the button way, i.e. its really connected to the proper actor), then make sure the API call is formatted correctly. Can you please share your API call, to see the corrected paramters are passed?

Comment: I have another solution using a $15 WebSockets plugin that works as expected, but I would still be curious to understand why it wouldh't work using the built-in remote API.

Comment: Thanks to the mods for being vigilant of the ChatGPT answers.